# Referencing multiple instance though data in another block in the same file in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In a single file in Terraform I'm creating a few instances of a serviceid called service.

I need the `xxxiam_service_id.service.id` of all these instances to create an access group.

If I try to use a `for_each` in the `xxiam_access_group_members` resource, it fails.

How can I retrieve multiple previous related instances and reference them in a new block in the same file?

```
resource "xxiam_access_group" "acc" {
  for_each = toset(var.ag_name)
  name = each.key
  description = var.ag_description
}

resource "xxiam_service_id" "service" {
  for_each = toset(var.ag_name)
  name = "service_id_${each.key}"
  description = "Service accessing ag ${each.key}"

}

data "xxiam_service_id" "data_service" {
  for_each = toset(var.ag_name)
  instance_id = each.key
}


resource "xxiam_access_group_members" "acname" {
  access_group_id = xxiam_access_group.acc.id
  iam_service_ids = [data.xxiam_service_id.data_service.id]
}
```

Comment: So this is all in the same module, i.e., same file?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, everything in the same file.

Comment: Do you need all the ids in the `iam_service_ids` or you want one per member?

Comment: I updated the original post. Basically, I need to add a specific list of service_ids to the access group. So I need to create a "xxiam_access_group_members"."acname" resource per each access_group_id and iam_service_ids. I'm not sure if I explained myself well enough. Basically I need to put in the last block more than one instance in access_group_id and iam_service_ids and not sure how can I do that in TF.

Comment: I think I understood, I added an answer. Btw, any reason to have `xx` in front of the resource name if that is AWS provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implicit references and the same variable with `for_each` in the `xxiam_access_group_members` resource:

```
resource "xxiam_access_group" "acc" {
  for_each    = toset(var.ag_name)
  name        = each.key
  description = var.ag_description
}

resource "xxiam_service_id" "service" {
  for_each    = toset(var.ag_name)
  name        = "service_id_${each.key}"
  description = "Service accessing ag ${each.key}"

}

resource "xxiam_access_group_members" "acname" {
  for_each        = toset(var.ag_name)
  access_group_id = xxiam_access_group.acc[each.key].id
  iam_service_ids = [xxiam_service_id.service[each.key].id]
}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected

Comment: │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type │ │ on main.tf line 30, in resource "xxiam_access_group_members" "acname": │ 30: iam_service_ids = xxiam_service_id.service[each.key].id │ ├──────────────── │ │ each.key is "acname-8" │ │ xxiam_access_group.acname is object with 9 attributes │ │ Inappropriate value for attribute "iam_service_ids": set of string required.

Comment: Maybe because the iam_service_ids is coming from xxiam_service_id.service which has a different name than xxiam_access_group.acc

Comment: I think I have made a mistake which I have corrected now, can you try again? Btw, which provider is this? AWS?

Comment: Yes it's AWS I'm just translating things from a different provider to AWS. However, in my code I have correct resources names from AWS. It seems working now! Thanks!! But my question is why I do not need a "[]" in access_group_id but I need in iam_service_ids?

Comment: Well, for one, whenever you see plural in any of the names of the arguments, you should assume it expects a set or a list, hence `iam_service_ids` expects a set. On the other hand, `access_group_id` is singular, i.e., it expects only one value to be provided. If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.